# How to make a path where the files will be created in?

Tags: python

I made a program that would create new text files every second but how can I make a path when those text files would be created in? (Example: Desktop)

Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
import string
import random

def getR():
p = ""
for _ in range(0, 10):
    p += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
return p
getR()

n = input("Are you sure you want to start this program?. \n")
if n == "yes":
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        f = open("{}.txt".format(getR()), "w+")
        f.close()
        sleep (1)
else:
  print("Closing the file...")
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create the files in your `Desktop` folder instead of the current working directory ?

Comment: Yes in desktop folder for example

Comment: As a side note, don't ever ask "are you sure you want to start this program".  If they didn't want to start it, they wouldn't have started it.  Just do your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you ask, although why you want to create an infinite number of randomly named empty files on your desktop is beyond me.

```
import os
from time import sleep
import string
import random

def getR():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    desktop = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + "/Desktop/"
    while True:
        f = open(desktop + "{}.txt".format(getR()), "w+")
        f.close()
        sleep (1)
```

Comment: btw if file creation is the goal then perhaps it is better to use `'x'` as the mode for `open` (which adds a small safety feature that will ensure that some file that coincidentally has the same file name and is located on desktop doesn't get overwritten by nothing), and also `random` has a `choices` function so there is no need for using `range` and `choice`

Answer (score 1):

To change the working directory use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```py
import os

os.chdir(PATH)
```

Or you can specify the path directly on `open`:

```py
file = os.path.join(PATH, FILENAME)
f = open(file, 'w+')
```